# Delete/Unable/ Mark combo box answers on PowerApps

Tags: combobox, powerapps

I'm building an app with PowerApps and I have a combo box with several options that can only be picked once. Is there a way to delete/unable/mark an option after it has been chosen?

Answer (score 0):

Just press the x next to the chosen option you want to unselect.

[image]